# What do you use for the Host name when trying to connect to a local MSSQL database in Django?

Tags: sql-server, django

My database settings look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'Test',
    'USER': 'Dev1',
    'PASSWORD': '******',
    'HOST': 'Compname\\TESTDB',
    'PORT': '1433',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        'unicode_results': True,
    },
},
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The host name should be the client host name (e.g. compname) or omitted.

Comment: @DanGuzman Apparently have my port set was causing the problem. You need to leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. When using a local MSSQL you have to leave the port empty. So it would look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'Test',
    'USER': 'Dev1',
    'PASSWORD': '*************',
    'HOST': 'ComputerName\\TESTDB',
    'PORT': '',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        'unicode_results': True,
    },
},
}
```